# Python MATPLOT LIB 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I'm just starting out with matplot lib trying to draw a 3d surface of a differential. Specifically I have an assignment to write my own ArcTan function, seen in the code as ExtArcTan and compare its value to that of pythons own, seen in the code as atan. I do this for different values of X and N. N refers to the number of series terms in my function, since it is effectively a Taylor approximation.

I start out by creating x and N arrays:

```
  N=np.arange(50)
  X=np.arange(-5,6) 
  N,X=np.meshgrid(N,X)
```

I then need to calculate the given differential for each of those two variables and the following code is what throws up error.

```
Diff=abs(ExtArcTan(X,N)-atan(X))
```

Without the final array I can't complete the trivial task of putting the arrays into the plot to generate the surface.

I get this error on the Diff line:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong:

For reference:

```
def ArcTanComponent(x,i): #calculates the ith component of arctan(x) taylor series
   return (((-1)**i)/(2*i+1))*(x**(2*i+1))

def BaseArcTan(x,N): #calculates all components for given N and sums to give approximation of arctan(x)
   Components=[]
   for i in range(N+1):
       Components.append(ArcTanComponent(x,i))
   return np.sum(Components)

def ExtArcTan(x,N): #extends baseArcTan function to work over entire range
    if (x>0):
        return PI/2 - BaseArcTan(1/x,N)
    elif(x<0):
         return -PI/2 - BaseArcTan(1/x,N)
    elif(x==0):
         return 0
```

Answer (score -1):

In `ExtArcTan(x,N)` you use `if x>0:` (and other comparisons) which is ambiguous if `x` is an array as the error says. And you send `X` from `N,X=np.meshgrid(N,X)` which is an array. You need to use an element by element check with `np.where` for example instead of checking the whole array with `x==0`.

EDIT: What about something along this (untested):

```
def ExtArcTan(x,N):
    x = np.sum(ArcTanComponent(x,i) for i in range(N+1))
    if (x>0):
        return PI/2 - BaseArcTan(1/x,N)
    elif(x<0):
         return -PI/2 - BaseArcTan(1/x,N)
    elif(x==0):
         return 0

EAT = np.array([[ExtArcTan(x,N) for x in row] for row in X])
Diff=abs(EAT-atan(X))
```

Comment: I see thank you Without completely re writing my function to accept arrays is there an easier way to generate the differential array?

Comment: Your problem is not in computing `Diff`, it is that your `ExtArcTan` function is buggy and you need to fix it, or you need to call it on each element separately.

Comment: I realise that. The thing is for the purpose of this assignment the only need of the function to handle arrays would be for this specific graphing  task so I'm wondering how I can create a diff array manually which would be quicker than adapting the function. Do I just generate a 2d array whose index values match up with the inputs. I'm not familiar for what matplotlib wants as z input exactly!

Comment: Yeah an idiot has been downvoting me a few times for no apparent reason... anyway did that help?

Comment: im still getting a weird error. I'll try working on it tonight. "only integer scalars can be converted to index" or something along those lines